# How to fix snap on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, snap, apparmor

I have a problem with snap. For example when I try to run firefox I have this error :

```
pc:~$ firefox
cannot open /tmp/snap-private-tmp: Permission denied
```

When I look the log I have :

```
kernel: audit: type=1400 audit: apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=16346 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"

kernel: audit: type=1400 audit: apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/tmp/snap-private-tmp/" pid=16346 comm="snap-confine" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

I also can't open "Ubuntu sotfware"

What needs to be done to make firefox run and fix snap ?

Comment: Is this a bog-standard Ubuntu 22.04 install? Did it ever work? What changed?

Comment: It's not a bug and yes it was working before. Nothing changed but after a reboot, I noticed this problem